What is the Opposite of Transactional Networking called?
I was reading an article which states:

Transactional networking, or networking done only with the purpose of advancement, can make the other person feel used.
On the other hand, networking done with the intention of making connections and exchanging knowledge benefits both parties and feels more authentic.  It triggers our reciprocity bias, which states that the people we help are more likely to help us in return.

So what is the other kind of networking called, since they don't name it?

I am not really sure if this question belongs to this site "Workplace" (although I did not downvote).

@Job_September_2020 Well thanks for not down-voting it; which is more than I can say for the other 5x insecure people.

I'd call it developing friendships and staying in touch with your friends. Which is the only kind of networking that actually works.
The problem is that "networking" is now being misused to describe things that aren't networking and don't work. It it doesn't take a serious investment of time and energy on each relationship, it isn't networking, it's wishful thinking. Unfortunately there are people who make a lot of money claiming otherwise.

My thought as well. Surprised this doesn't have more upvotes.

@questor: Networking has been misdescribed, and oversold, by those who are trying to sell articles, books, and services. Their target audience, which is the people who are looking for a magic wand that does not require effort or experience, does not react well to being told this.

From a pure linguistics point of view:
Mutual Networking
But whether that is a thing or a term - I don't know.
Maybe we can make it a thing.

Maybe, it is called Social Network.

My experience is that most networking on social networks is transactional. Looking at you, LinkedIn.

Social networking sites, and being social, are very different things.
